# How to Stringify the json in java without using js

Tags: java, json

I have the String like

```
[{"Subject":"Java","Teacher":"Pavan"}]
```

and I want it as

```
[{\"Subject\":\"Java\",\"Teacher\":\"Pavan\"}]
```

I tried `String toconvert=jsarray.toString().replaceAll("\"", "\\");` also

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a library such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
 or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: I disagree with the proposed duplicate - this question is about Java, not JavaScript (the proposed duplicate is about JavaScript).

Comment: Did you tried `replaceAll("\"", "\\\"")` ?

Comment: Your call to `replaceAll` is wrong.  You are actually replacing a quote by a backslash. It should be `String toconvert=jsarray.toString().replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");`

Comment: it should be `replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");` , but the question is why would you want that?

Comment: actually i need to send data in stringify format . - @nafas

Comment: jsarray.toString().replaceAll("\"", "\\\""); is also not workin -@Pierre

Comment: @pawansharma *Why* do you need to make such a conversion? If you want to *send* data, you should leave the JSON unharmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
String toconvert=jsarray.toString().replaceAll("\\\"", "\\\\\"");
```

Basically, your code did just replace all quotes with backslash. What you need is to replace all quotes with backslash-quote.

For a simple case as you shown it may be enough, but be aware that this code does not handle the case where the quotes are already escaped (eg. the string "pouet \" pouet" will result in "pouet \\" pouet", thus become invalid)

EDIT: you need to escape the quotes and backslash, once for java, and once for the regexp engine (which have a special meaning for quotes and backslash as well)